# R and shiny: How to pass a list of lists (instead of a list of values) in choiceValues in the various input controls of shiny, like the radio buttons

Tags: r, input, shiny, controls

I try to build a small shinyapp with two inputs. The second input should use values from the first input. This works fine if "single" values are passed. In the following examples, the slideinput takes the values from the radio buttons, either 1, 5 or 10 year and then adjusts the sliderinput going back 1, 5, 10 years respectively. So far so.

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Changing the values of inputs"),
  fluidRow(
    radioButtons("control_num", 
                 "Choose time span:",
                 choiceNames = list("10 years",
                                    "5 years",
                                    "1 year"),
                 choiceValues = list(10,
                                     5,
                                     3 ),
                 inline = T),
    sliderInput(inputId = "inSlider2", 
                label = "timeline:",
                min = as.Date("2001-01-01") , 
                max = as.Date("2016-12-31"),
                value =  c(as.Date( "2011-01-01")  , as.Date("2013-01-01" ) ),
                step = 1,
                width = "90%"
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    c_num <- as.numeric( input$control_num )
    c_num1 <- as.Date("2016-12-31") - years( c_num )   
    c_num2 <- as.Date("2016-12-31")

    # Slider range input 
    updateSliderInput(session, "inSlider2",
                      value = c(c_num1 , c_num2) )
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, if I want to pass a list of lists, e.g. several date ranges, say calendar year 2015, 2014 and 2013. Each of these consists of a list of two dates: start date (1st Jan) and end date (31st Dec). 
The problems shows up when I try to pass this list of lists in "choiceValues" instead of a list of values.

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Changing the values of inputs from the server"),
  fluidRow(

    radioButtons("control_num2", 
                 "Choose time span:",
                 choiceNames = list("2015",
                                    "2014",
                                    "2013"),
                 choiceValues = list(c(as.Date("2015-01-01" ), as.Date("2015-12-31") ),
                                     c(as.Date("2014-01-01" ), as.Date("2014-12-31") ),
                                     c(as.Date("2013-01-01" ), as.Date("2013-12-31") )
                                     ),
                 inline = T),

    sliderInput(inputId = "inSlider2", 
                label = "timeliner:",
                min = as.Date("2001-01-01") , 
                max = as.Date("2016-12-31"),
                value =  c(as.Date( "2011-01-01")  , as.Date("2013-01-01" ) ),
                step = 1,
                width = "90%"
    )

  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    c_num <-  input$control_num2 
    c_num1 <- as.list(input$control_num2 )  

    # used to check the structure of the input variable
    updateNumericInput(session, "control_num2",
                       label = paste("Input ", c_num, 
                                     "Input as list: ", c_num1,
                                     "First element of list: ", c_num1[1] ),
                       value = c_num)

    # Slider range input 
    updateSliderInput(session, "inSlider2",
                      value = c_num  )


  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When the parameters is evaluated in the observe part of the code, the "input$conrol_num" is always taken as a list of character with length of one.
I had some warnings along these lines.
So I guess there is no possiblity to pass a list of lists here. What would be an elegant way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks it's possible to have lists or vectors as values in an input. Try having a unique id string for each value, pass that on to the server, then look up the value in a named list. e.g.

```
# in UI
radioButtons("control_num2", 
             "Choose time span:",
             choiceNames = c("2015","2014","2013"),
             choiceValues = c("year2015", "year2014", "year2015")
             inline = T)


# in server
idmap <- list("year2015" = c(as.Date("2015-01-01" ), as.Date("2015-12-31") ),
              "year2014" = c(as.Date("2014-01-01" ), as.Date("2014-12-31") ),
              "year2013" = c(as.Date("2013-01-01" ), as.Date("2013-12-31") ))

observe({
    req(input$control_num2)
    c_num <-  idmap[[input$control_num2]] 
    # Slider range input 
    updateSliderInput(session, "inSlider2",
                      value = c_num )
})
```

[edit] sorry, there was a typo in `updateSliderInput`. Complete working version:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Changing the values of inputs from the server"),
  fluidRow(
    radioButtons("control_num2", 
                 "Choose time span:",
                 choices=c("2015"="year2015", "2014"="year2014", "2013"="year2013"),
                 inline = T),
    sliderInput(inputId = "inSlider2", 
                label = "timeliner:",
                min = as.Date("2001-01-01") , 
                max = as.Date("2016-12-31"),
                value =  c(as.Date( "2011-01-01")  , as.Date("2013-01-01" ) ),
                step = 1,
                width = "90%")))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  idmap <- list("year2015" = c(as.Date("2015-01-01" ), as.Date("2015-12-31") ),
                "year2014" = c(as.Date("2014-01-01" ), as.Date("2014-12-31") ),
                "year2013" = c(as.Date("2013-01-01" ), as.Date("2013-12-31") ))

  observe({
    req(input$control_num2)
    c_num <-  idmap[[input$control_num2]] 
    # Slider range input 
    updateSliderInput(session, "inSlider2",
                      value = c_num )
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I got your idea and logic. Do you mind posting the complete code? I tried but get weird warnings and shinyapps does not work at all.

Comment: Third time's the charm - this version works for me. I didn't subset the list correctly the first time; I really should know better.